# How to make a phone call using intent in Android wear?

Tags: wear-os

Code like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0987654321"))
startActivity(intent);
```

works perfectly well on smartphone (the phone call occurs immediately), but not on smartwatch - there we can see a menu

[image: "Choose calling device : Call from watch / Call from phone"]

that waits for user's manual selection. Is it possible to perform this selection from the application or somehow close this window?

Comment: Based from this [forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/3ot8eq/android_wear_rest_calls_from_watch_device/?st=jchtatdj&sh=17dad987), you cannot do network connects right from the watch, you need to do the call through your phone. Check this [blog](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/a-guide-to-the-android-wear-message-api/152) for more information.

Comment: Why not? Smartwatch have sim-card and connected to network, I can do the call manually.
Probably, I should   perform selection "Call from watch" from my application (emulate touch screen or something like that). But it can be rather difficult...

Comment: Have you tried ACTION_CALL for this?